# Imported library 'ExcelLibrary' contains no keywords

Tags: eclipse, robotframework, jython

Have created maven project and done robot framework setup in eclipse using jython. 
Getting "Imported library 'ExcelLibrary' contains no keywords." warning message while running the script and ExcelLibrary keywords have not been recognized.

Any help to resolve this issue?

Comment: try to generate list of keywords from command line and see what you would get: python -m robot.libdoc <path to excelLibrary python file> list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the path of ExcelLibrary explicitly in the POM xml resolved this issue.

```
<extraPathDirectory>C:\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\ExcelLibrary</extraPathDirectory>
```